# trigger event sibling inherited javascript odontogram

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

We need an application when the user selects an element in one container and this container need to add this element to another container (lets call container-2) and this last container also only trigger events on that elements an so on. What is the best wey to achieve that.

For example:

[image]

Each tab has a serial of containers (theets) and each theet has an events (all tabs are the same structure). Those events adds that theet to a container on the next tab, and must "draw" (select) the theet in that tab and only can made trigger event on that theet in that tab.

I don't know if I made myself understood?

Thanks for all your help.

I'm sorry for my english.

Comment: odontograms are (extensive, complete) electronic dental health records, yes? And you're asking about one aspect of that. I don't see how your question can be answered here. odontogram things such as "tabs", "containers", "events", and "theets" have  deeper structure and meaning, so you've said. And then they must work within the larger context of some unknown complex application. This is all much to general and vague to begin to answer.

Comment: thanks @radarbob, yes, you're right. This is an extensive program. But in this case it's just putting it in certain context. I only need that part of the events in javascript. Each container is inherited. I don't know if you understand me?